# variable manipulation in a for loop

Tags: loops, variables, batch-file, for-loop

So my batch code is supposed to print out a string of numbers one by one. My problem is it seems to get stuck in the first letter. I have (I believe) an manipulation command to remove the first number of the string but it doesn't seem to work. If for example the info.txt would be 12345678 the :loop would get stuck in 1.

```
:floop
for /F %%G IN ('TYPE info.txt') DO call :line1 %%G
goto :end

:line1
set /a cnt+=1
set /a div=%cnt% %% 2
if %div% == 0 call :line2 %1
goto :EOF

:line2
set ord=%1
echo %ord%
pause

:loop
pause
set var=%ord%
set char=%var:~0,1%
set var=%var:~1%
echo %char%
if NOT %var%==_end goto loop
goto floop

:end
```

Comment: See the Set command help on delayed environment variable expansion. To actually use it see the setlocal command.

Answer (score 0):

As phd443322 comments, you need to investigate `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

`help set` goes into it a bit.

I also found an msdn blog post here that goes into this at length: [msdn blog post (Raymond Chen ?)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx#comments)

Here's an example that I got to work based on your original problem statement:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:floop

for /F %%G IN ('TYPE info.txt') DO call :line1 %%G
goto :end

:line1
        set ord=%1
        echo %ord%
        set var=%ord%
:loop
    pause
    set char=!var:~0,1!
    set var=!var:~1!
    echo !char!
    if [!var!] == [] goto :end
goto loop
:end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:loop
pause
set var=%ord%
set char=%var:~0,1%
set var=%var:~1%
echo %char%
if NOT %var%==_end goto loop
goto floop
```

Your first problem is in this part^^

You are setting `var` to the value of `ord`; `char` to the first charater of `var`; `var` to the rest after the first; displaying `char` (the first character) and then looping back to setting `var` from `ord`...

```
:OLD_loop
pause
set var=%ord%
:loop
pause
set char=%var:~0,1%
set var=%var:~1%
echo %char%
if NOT %var%==_end goto loop
goto floop
```

This should cure that problem.

**but** you should then consider what happens if `var` does **not** terminate `_end`. Eventually, `var` will become empty, and `cmd` will try to interpret the line

```
if NOT ==_end goto loop
```

which it will call a syntax error.

(you could fix this by coding

```
:OLD_loop
pause
set var=%ord%_end
:loop
```

)

But then - what happens when `var` is trimmed down to `_end`? `GOTO floop` will read the file again, starting at the first line, processing it, eventually finding `var`=`_end`, back to `floop`, er - we've been here before.... After a while, cmd will run out of stack space because processing your file calls the subroutine, but never returns...